# How to capitalize the first letter of a string in dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, letter, capitalize

How do I capitalize the first character of a string, while not changing the case of any of the other letters?

For example, "this is a string" should give "This is a string".

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Since dart version 2.6, dart supports extensions:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
    String capitalize() {
      return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
    }
}
```

So you can just call your extension like this:

```
import "string_extension.dart";

var someCapitalizedString = "someString".capitalize();
```

Comment: Extension should return `return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";`. If not it will capitalize correctly 'this' but not 'THIS'.

Comment: don't you normally check if a value is valid before operating with it?

Comment: We either have to check isEmpty inside capitalize() or leave it up to the caller. My preference is for the caller so the code doesn't need to get littered with .isEmpty() checks. You can add `if (isEmpty) return this` as the first line.

Comment: gotta check if this is empty to avoid the crash. i dont think toLowerCase() would crash with an empty string and neither should your extension

Comment: you should add some checks if string is not null - eg:

   `if (this == null || this == "") return ""; `

Comment: I thought I liked Dart.... but this is quite special. Why wouldn't they have something like this in the core language? I wonder what else is missing!

Comment: I just use:
someString = someString[0].toUpperCase() + someString.substring(1).toLowerCase();

Comment: You can no longer check for nullability on extensions,so you can skip that check, but still checking for the length of it can help you avoid minor issues when converting empty strings and 1-char strings

Answer (score 294):

Copy this somewhere:

```
extension StringCasingExtension on String {
  String toCapitalized() => length > 0 ?'${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1).toLowerCase()}':'';
  String toTitleCase() => replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ').split(' ').map((str) => str.toCapitalized()).join(' ');
}
```

Usage:

```dart
// import StringCasingExtension

final helloWorld = 'hello world'.toCapitalized(); // 'Hello world'
final helloWorld = 'hello world'.toUpperCase(); // 'HELLO WORLD'
final helloWorldCap = 'hello world'.toTitleCase(); // 'Hello World'
```

Comment: will complain when string is empty or not long enough.

Comment: @RishiDua well as a dev, (by default) we have the responsibility to check for those conditions ‍

Comment: `str.capitalize` is _not defined_. So you use `str.inCaps`

Comment: ```Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0```

Comment: ```final helloWorld = 'hello   world'.capitalizeFirstofEach;```

Answer (score 190):

Substring parsing in the other answers do not account for locale variances.
The [toBeginningOfSentenceCase()](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/toBeginningOfSentenceCase.html) function in the `intl/intl.dart` package handles basic sentence-casing and the dotted "i" in Turkish and Azeri.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show toBeginningOfSentenceCase;

print(toBeginningOfSentenceCase('this is a string'));
```

Result:
`This is a string`

Comment: This with addition to the extension method answer should be the answer. If you already use the intl package there is no reason to reinvent the wheel with the extension.

Comment: Yes this is correct answer if you want to handle different locales in the right way. +1

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues - Even if you are not currently using Intl this is a better answer, because this package is maintained by the Flutter / Dart team, while the extension method has to be maintained by the developer.

Comment: It's an extension. Why would it need to be maintained?

Comment: This doesn't really do any locale-specific logic at present (just capitalises the first letter, handling Turkish i specially). But it might be expanded in the future.

Comment: You are an example of why ChatGPT can't replace human intelligence. Generally, we use this package and it's redundant to add one more package for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 82):

```dart
void main() {
  print(capitalize("this is a string"));
  // displays "This is a string"
}

String capitalize(String s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
```

See this snippet running on DartPad : https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c8ffb8995abe259e9643

Comment: `s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();` in case the string is all upper case to start with.

Answer (score 22):

There is a utils package that covers this function. It has some more nice methods for operation on strings.

Install it with :

```
dependencies:
  basic_utils: ^1.2.0
```

Usage :

```dart
String capitalized = StringUtils.capitalize("helloworld");
```

Github:

https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Dart-Basic-Utils

Comment: nice package. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 22):

Super late, but I use,

```dart
String title = "some string with no first letter caps";
    
title = title.replaceFirst(title[0], title[0].toUpperCase()); // Some string with no...
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use this package in flutter 
[ReCase](https://pub.dev/packages/recase)
It gives you various case conversion functionalities like:

- snake_case
- dot.case
- path/case
- param-case
- PascalCase
- Header-Case
- Title Case
- camelCase
- **Sentence case**
- CONSTANT_CASE

  ```
  ReCase sample = new ReCase('hello world');

  print(sample.sentenceCase); // Prints 'Hello world'
  ```

Comment: Great library!!

Comment: Looks great. Use with caution as there's only one test, however much you may dig the test case. `String mockText = 'This is-Some_sampleText. YouDig?';`

Answer (score 8):

```
void allWordsCapitilize (String str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().split(' ').map((word) {
      String leftText = (word.length > 1) ? word.substring(1, word.length) : '';
      return word[0].toUpperCase() + leftText;
    }).join(' ');
}
allWordsCapitilize('THIS IS A TEST'); //This Is A Test
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should add more note to explain in order to help the OP know the reason why.

Comment: ```Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0```

Comment: ```String data = allWordsCapitilize('THIS   IS A TEST') ;```

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned before by Ephenodrom,
you can add basic_utils package in your pubspeck.yaml and use it in your dart files like this:

```
StringUtils.capitalize("yourString");
```

That's acceptable for a single function, but in a larger chain of operations, it becomes awkward.

As explained in [Dart language documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.6/static-extension-members/feature-specification.md#dart-static-extension-methods-design):

```
doMyOtherStuff(doMyStuff(something.doStuff()).doOtherStuff())
```

That code is much **less readable** than:

```
something.doStuff().doMyStuff().doOtherStuff().doMyOtherStuff()
```

The code is also much **less discoverable** because an IDE can suggest `doMyStuff()` after `something.doStuff()`, but will be unlikely to suggest putting `doMyOtherStuff(…)` around the expression.

For these reasons, I think you should add an extension method to String type (you can do it since dart 2.6!) like this:

```
/// Capitalize the given string [s]
/// Example : hello => Hello, WORLD => World
extension Capitalized on String {
  String capitalized() => this.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

and call it using dot notation:

```
'yourString'.capitalized()
```

or, if your value can be null, replacing the dot with a '?.' in the invocation:

```
myObject.property?.toString()?.capitalized()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using get: ^4.6.5 as state management with flutter then there are inbuilt extensions for capitalizing

```
        // This will capitalize first letter of every word
        print('hello world'.capitalize); // Hello World

        // This will capitalize first letter of sentence
        print('hello world'.capitalizeFirst); // Hello world

        // This will remove all white spaces from sentence
        print('hello world'.removeAllWhitespace); // helloworld

        // This will convert string to lowerCamelCase
        print('This is new world'.camelCase); // thisIsNewWorld

        // This will remove all white spaces between the two words and replace it with '-'
        print('This is new    world'.paramCase); // this-is-new-world
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String capitalize(String s) => (s != null && s.length > 1)
    ? s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)
    : s != null ? s.toUpperCase() : null;
```

It passes tests:

```
test('null input', () {
  expect(capitalize(null), null);
});
test('empty input', () {
  expect(capitalize(''), '');
});
test('single char input', () {
  expect(capitalize('a'), 'A');
});
test('crazy input', () {
  expect(capitalize('?a!'), '?a!');
});
test('normal input', () {
  expect(capitalize('take it easy bro!'), 'Take it easy bro!');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String? toCapitalize(String? input) {
  if (input == null || input.isEmpty) return input;
  return '${input[0].toUpperCase()}${input.substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
}
```

or Extension:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String? toCapitalize() {
    if (this == null || this.isEmpty) return this;
    return '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To check for null and empty string cases, also using the short notations:

```
  String capitalizeFirstLetter(String s) =>
  (s?.isNotEmpty ?? false) ? '${s[0].toUpperCase()}${s.substring(1)}' : s;
```

Comment: I don't think this checks for `null`.

Answer (score 4):

you can you use capitalize() method of the strings librarie, it's now availabe in the 0.1.2 version,
and make sure to add the dependencie in the pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  strings: ^0.1.2
```

and import it into the dart file :

```
import 'package:strings/strings.dart';
```

and now you can use the method which has the following prototype:

```
String capitalize(String string)
```

Example :

```
print(capitalize("mark")); => Mark
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var original = "this is a string";
var changed = original.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + original.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also check if the string is null or empty.

```
String capitalize(String input) {
  if (input == null) {
    throw new ArgumentError("string: $input");
  }
  if (input.length == 0) {
    return input;
  }
  return input[0].toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another alternative to capitalize Strings in dart with the use of the String class Method [`splitMapJoin`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/String/splitMapJoin.html):

```
var str = 'this is a test';
str = str.splitMapJoin(RegExp(r'\w+'),onMatch: (m)=> '${m.group(0)}'.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() +'${m.group(0)}'.substring(1).toLowerCase() ,onNonMatch: (n)=> ' ');
print(str);  // This Is A Test
```

Comment: good solution, but doesn't work with letters with diacritics

Comment: it's normal because of the regex if you wish to do it adjust the regex to include those letters

Comment: I think a simpler Implementation is to handle the whitespace, not the words in the regex

just change it with `str = str.trim().splitMapJoin(
        RegExp(r'\s+'),
        onMatch: (m) => ' ',
        onNonMatch: (n) {
          return '${n.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}${n.substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
        },
      ).trim(); `

Comment: the best solution

Answer (score 3):

Weird this is not available in dart to begin with. Below is an extension to capitalize a `String`:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String capitalized() {
    if (this.isEmpty) return this;
    return this[0].toUpperCase() + this.substring(1);
  }
}
```

It checks that the `String` is not empty to begin with, then it just capitalizes the first letter and adds the rest

Usage:

```
import "path/to/extension/string_extension_file_name.dart";

var capitalizedString = '${'alexander'.capitalized()} ${'hamilton, my name is'.capitalized()} ${'alexander'.capitalized()} ${'hamilton'.capitalized()}');
// Print result: "Alexander Hamilton, my name is Alexander Hamilton"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use characters rather than code units

As described in the article [Dart string manipulation done right](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-string-manipulation-done-right-5abd0668ba3e) (see Scenario 4), whenever you are dealing with user input you should use `characters` rather than the index.

```dart
// import 'package:characters/characters.dart';

final sentence = 'e\u0301tienne is eating.'; // étienne is eating.
final firstCharacter = sentence.characters.first.toUpperCase();
final otherCharacters = sentence.characters.skip(1);
final capitalized = '$firstCharacter$otherCharacters';
print(capitalized); // Étienne is eating.
```

In this particular example it would still work even if you were using the index, but it's still a good idea to get into the habit of using `characters`.

The [characters](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) package comes with Flutter so there is no need for the import. In a pure Dart project you need to add the import but you don't have to add anything to pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response. I'm curious, what would be the benefit of `characters`?

Answer (score 3):

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String capitalize() {
    return this
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1, word.length))
        .join(" ");
  }
}
```

For anyone interested, this should work on any string

Answer (score 3):

In range checked.
Idiomatic as of Dart >2.16.1

As a function

```
String capitalize(String str) =>
    str.isNotEmpty
        ? str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)
        : str;
```

As an extension

```
extension StringExtension on String {
    String get capitalize => 
        isNotEmpty 
            ? this[0].toUpperCase() + substring(1) 
            : this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the Dart version is 2.12 or later, one of the simple and effective solutions to this problem would be,

```
extension Capitalizing on String {
    String get capitalized {
        if (isEmpty) return '';
        return replaceFirst(this[0], this[0].toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Writing an `extension` on `String` class ensures code reusability and clean syntax, you can utilize the extension like this,

```
String yourString = 'this is a string';
final String capitalizedString = yourString.capitalized; //This is a string
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me.

```
String name = 'amina';    

print(${name[0].toUpperCase()}${name.substring(1).toLowerCase()});
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is here:

First make the string's first letter to uppercase using its index then concate the rest of the string.

Here username is the string.

username[0].toUpperCase() + username.substring(1);

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function:

```dart
String capitalize(String str) {
  return str
      .split(' ')
      .map((word) => word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1))
      .join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the more popular other answers don't seem to handle `null` and `''`. I prefer to not have to deal with those situations in client code, I just want a `String` in return no matter what - even if that means an empty one in case of `null`.

```
String upperCaseFirst(String s) => (s??'').length<1 ? '' : s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Text_Tools package, is simple to use:

https://pub.dev/packages/text_tools

Your code would be like this:

```
//This will print 'This is a string
print(TextTools.toUppercaseFirstLetter(text: 'this is a string'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another unhealthy way I found of solving this issue is to

```
String myName = "shahzad";

print(myName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + myName.substring(1));
```

this will produce the same effect but is pretty dirty way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Hannah Stark answer, but it crashes the app, if the string is empty, so here is improved version of the solution with the extension:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String capitalize() {
    if(this.length > 0) {
      return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1)}";
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
extension EasyString on String {
  String toCapitalCase() {
   var lowerCased = this.toLowerCase();
   return lowerCased[0].toUpperCase() + lowerCased.substring(1);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
capitalize("your text");
```

simply wrap that text to capitalize widget and it makes your text (your text) to (Your text)
..
have a great day

Answer (score 1):

Simple without any extension:

```
title = "some title without first capital"

title.replaceRange(0, 1, title[0].toUpperCase())

// Result: "Some title without first capital"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Text("hello world".capitalize.toString(), style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can capitalize each word of a string by define the capitalize() method.

```
extension StringExtensions on String {
  String capitalize() {
    return '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1)}';
  }
}
```

how to use?

```
String myString = 'capitalized_the_first_letter_of_every_word_the_string';

myString = myString.replaceAll('_', ' ');

String capitalizedString = myString.split(' ').map((word) => word.capitalize()).join(' ');
```

code example :

```
class CapitalizeText extends StatefulWidget {
  const CapitalizeText({super.key});

  @override
  State<CapitalizeText> createState() => _CapitalizeTextState();
}

class _CapitalizeTextState extends State<CapitalizeText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    String myString = 'capitalized_the_first_letter_of_every_word_the_string';

    myString = myString.replaceAll('_', ' ');

    String capitalizedString = myString.split(' ').map((word) => word.capitalize()).join(' ');

    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(
        'Capitalized String - $capitalizedString',
        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200, fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }
}

extension StringExtensions on String {
  String capitalize() {
    return '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${substring(1)}';
  }
}
```

> Input: ***capitalized_the_first_letter_of_every_word_the_string***

> Output: ***Capitalized The First Letter Of Every Word The String***

Answer (score 0):

```
String fullNameString =
    txtControllerName.value.text.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
        txtControllerName.value.text.trim().substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer using dart String methods.

```
String name = "big";
String getFirstLetter = name.substring(0, 1);    
String capitalizedFirstLetter =
      name.replaceRange(0, 1, getFirstLetter.toUpperCase());  
print(capitalizedFirstLetter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Herewith Sharing my answer

```
void main() {
  var data = allWordsCapitilize(" hi ram good day");
  print(data);
}

String allWordsCapitilize(String value) {
  var result = value[0].toUpperCase();
  for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (value[i - 1] == " ") {
      result = result + value[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      result = result + value[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a different implementation:

1. Create a class:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FirstLetterTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      //text: newValue.text?.toUpperCase(),
      text: normaliseName(newValue.text),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }

  /// Fixes name cases; Capitalizes Each Word.
  String normaliseName(String name) {
    final stringBuffer = StringBuffer();

    var capitalizeNext = true;
    for (final letter in name.toLowerCase().codeUnits) {
      // UTF-16: A-Z => 65-90, a-z => 97-122.
      if (capitalizeNext && letter >= 97 && letter <= 122) {
        stringBuffer.writeCharCode(letter - 32);
        capitalizeNext = false;
      } else {
        // UTF-16: 32 == space, 46 == period
        if (letter == 32 || letter == 46) capitalizeNext = true;
        stringBuffer.writeCharCode(letter);
      }
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();
  }
}
```

Then you import the class into any page you need eg in a TextField's inputFormatters property, just call the widget above like so:

```
TextField(
inputformatters: [FirstLetterTextFormatter()]),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code if you want to capitalize each word in a sentence, for example, if you want to capitalize each part of your customer's fullName, simply you can use the following extension in your model class:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String capitalizeFirstLetter() {
    return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
  }
}
```

and simply use this getter

```
String get formalFullName =>  fullName.capitalizeFirstLetter().splitMapJoin(RegExp(r' '),
                onNonMatch: (str) => str.toString().capitalize());
```

Hope this help someone

Answer (score 0):

```html
String myString = "hello world";
final capitalizedString = myString.replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ').split(' ').map((capitalizedString) => capitalizedString.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +capitalizedString.substring(1)).join(' ');

void main(){
print(capitalizedString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/any.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/choice.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/join.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/mapped.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/rest.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/sequence.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/value.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  print(capitalize('abc'));
  print(capitalize(''));
  print(capitalize('xyz'));
  print(capitalize('Abc'));
}

String capitalize(String s) {
  const p = Choice2(
    Join('', Sequence2(Mapped(Any(), _capitalize), Rest())),
    Value<String, String>(''),
  );
  return parseString(p.parse, s);
}

String _capitalize(String s) => s.toUpperCase();
```

This method is also quite fast.

```dart
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/any.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/choice.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/join.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/mapped.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/rest.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/sequence.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parser/value.dart';
import 'package:parser_combinator/parsing.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  const count = 1000000;
  final sw = Stopwatch();
  sw.start();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    'abc'.capitalize();
  }
  sw.stop();
  print('Low level: ${sw.elapsedMilliseconds / 1000} sec');
  sw.reset();
  sw.start();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    capitalize('abc');
  }
  sw.stop();
  print('High level: ${sw.elapsedMilliseconds / 1000} sec');
}

String capitalize(String s) {
  const p = Choice2(
    Join('', Sequence2(Mapped(Any(), _capitalize), Rest())),
    Value<String, String>(''),
  );
  return parseString(p.parse, s);
}

String _capitalize(String s) => s.toUpperCase();

extension StringExtension on String {
  String capitalize() {
    return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Low level: 0.084 sec
High level: 0.304 sec
```

Answer (score -1):

**As of 23/3/2021 Flutter 2.0.2**

Just use `yourtext.capitalizeFirst`

Comment: I can't find any reference to this. Can you provide source?

Comment: Sorry, its under a plugin, my bad. Use this : [link](https://pub.dev/packages/get#utils) . It has a lot of useful utilities

Comment: This is not available

Answer (score -1):

if you are using it in flutter use as below,

For first letter of string to capitalize :

```
Text("hello world".toString().capitalizeFirstLetter()),
```

Convert all letter of string to capital

```
Text("hello world".toString().toUpperCase()),
```

Convert all letter of string to small

```
Text("hello world".toString().toLowerCase()),
```

Comment: ``The method 'capitalizeFirstLetter' isn't defined for the type 'String'.`

Comment: @test can you explain it?  no need to write toString() for local string but if you are fetching string from Api's u need to use yourapistring.toString().capitalizeFirstLetter()

Answer (score -2):

Try this code to capitalize the first letter of any String in Dart - Flutter:

```
Example: hiii how are you

    Code:
     String str="hiii how are you";
     Text( '${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.substring(1)}',)`

Output: Hiii how are you
```

Answer (score -4):

final helloWorld = 'hello world'.toUpperCase();
Text(helloWorld);

Comment: That will capitalize the whole string, instead of the first character.