# Dart First Letter to Uppercase

Tags: string, dart

Is there any easiest or built-in method in dart to change First Letter of every word to Uppercase

ex: **system admin** to **System Admin**

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628989/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-dart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capitalize the first letter of a string in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628989/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not built in method to do so, you can achieve that in many ways, one could be:

```dart
var string = 'system admin';
StringBuffer titleCase = StringBuffer();

string.split(' ')
  .forEach((sub) {
    if (sub.trim().isEmpty)
        return;

    titleCase
      ..write(sub[0].toUpperCase())
      ..write(sub.substring(1))
      ..write(' ');
  });

print(titleCase.toString()); //Prints "System Admin"
```

Or can use the [recase package](https://pub.dev/packages/recase):

```dart
ReCase rc = ReCase('system admin');
(rc.titleCase); // Prints "System Admin"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use RegExp with String.replaceAllMapped

```
  var recase = RegExp(r'\b\w');
  var str = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
  print(str.replaceAllMapped(recase, (match) => match.group(0).toUpperCase()));
  // The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog
```

Comment: The RegExp could be just `RegExP(r"\b\w")`. The `\b` match is zero-with, so it's not necessary to put it into a look-behind. It contains its own look-behind because its match depends on the previous character.