# Flutter: How to capitalize a single word

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, how would you capitalize a single word? I know of **Text().toUpperCase()**, but I'd like to capitalize only the first letter, not the whole word. Will I need to use Regex, or does Flutter have a built-in function for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628989/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-dart

Comment: productName.text.toString()[0].toUpperCase() +
                productName.text.substring(1).toLowerCase()

Comment: it is [duplicate]  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628989/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
  String foo = 'example';
  String bar = '';

  if (foo.length > 0) { 
     bar = foo[0].toUpperCase() + foo.substring(1);
  }

  print(bar);   // Example
```