# Flutter Textfield Capitalize Each Word

Tags: flutter, textfield, inputformatter

```
class InputMdnWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputMdnWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _InputMdnWidgetState createState() => _InputMdnWidgetState();
}

class _InputMdnWidgetState extends State<InputMdnWidget> {
  TextEditingController _controller;
  
  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words       
    );
  }
}
```

i'm new to flutter, i have a textfield and using a controller, i want to make the text that the user typed into camel case,
for example the user types "lala lala", the text in the textfield will change to "Lala Lala", is this possible and how?

I use textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words doesn't work

Comment: can you add your Textfield widget with controller

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: are you trying on web ? it should work on phones.

Comment: Your code works for me with iOS simulator for example.

Comment: i try in real device android 10, but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [TextInputFormatters](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html). These make input conform to particular patterns, and can be supplied to `TextFields` like so:

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  inputFormatters: [MyInputFormatter()],       
);
```

If you want custom formatting, and I think you're wanting "title case," you can create your own `TextInputFormatter` by extending the class like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TitleCaseInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  String textToTitleCase(String text) {
    if (text.length > 1) {
      return text[0].toUpperCase() + text.substring(1);
      /*or text[0].toUpperCase() + text.substring(1).toLowerCase(), if you want absolute title case*/
    } else if (text.length == 1) {
      return text[0].toUpperCase();
    }

    return '';
  }

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    String formattedText = newValue.text
        .split(' ')
        .map((element) => textToTitleCase(element))
        .toList()
        .join(' ');
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: formattedText,
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

Again, use it like this:

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  inputFormatters: [TitleCaseInputFormatter()],       
);
```

Answer (score 3):

This way you can handle on `web` also. also you can check this answer for [format explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629114/10157127).

place it somewhere

```
extension CapExtension on String {
  String get inCaps =>
      this.length > 0 ? '${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1)}' : '';

  String get capitalizeFirstofEach => this
      .replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ')
      .split(" ")
      .map((str) => str.inCaps)
      .join(" ");
}
```

and use it like `text.capitalizeFirstofEach`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Expandeddd extends StatefulWidget {
  Expandeddd({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExpandedddState createState() => _ExpandedddState();
}


class _ExpandedddState extends State<Expandeddd> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      final text = controller.text;

      /// dont set Text here
      controller.selection =
          TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: text.length));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: 812,
          minHeight: 300,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              autocorrect: false,
              onChanged: (value) {
                controller.text = value.capitalizeFirstofEach;
              },
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i get error Class 'String' has no instance getter 'capitalizeFirstofEach'.

Comment: i added `extension CapExtension on String ` before the state class. you can place it anywhere

Comment: i just moved that extension at top level.

Comment: thank you this is work, but in last word get underlined