# How to turn capitalize my String's first letter in Text of flutter in dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to capitalize the first letter in text widget?

```
 Text("${_products[index]["product_name"]}",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.sp,),)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to say you want the first letter capital of that string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capitalize the first letter of a string in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628989/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in-dart)

Answer (score 3):

A function for capitalization of first letter

```
  String capitalizeOnlyFirstLater() {
    if(this.trim().isEmpty) return "";

    return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1)}";
  }
```

Then call the function in `text`

```
Text("${_products[index]["product_name"].capitalizeOnlyFirstLater()}",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.sp,),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first letter and convert it to uppercase and concatenate the rest with it.

```dart
final String productName = _products[index]["product_name"];
final String productNameInSentenceCase = productName[0] + productName.substring(1);

Text(productNameInSentenceCase, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.sp,),)
```