# Flutter - How to format a Api text

Tags: flutter, api

I'm trying to use a value from a API, but this value need some changes before show.

This is how I receive the value:

`Name.MAGIC`

and I want it to show like this:

`Magic`

Here's the code

```
Text(
  finalApi![widget.index].type.name.toString(),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 15,
     ),
  ),
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this `...toString().split('.')[1].toLowerCase()` . And read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528001/955594)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use this function:

```
String extractName(String text) {
List words = text.split(".");
String result = words.last.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + words.last.substring(1).toLowerCase();
return result ;
 }
print(extractName("Name.magic")); // Magic
```

in your case use this:

```
    Text(
  extractName(finalApi![widget.index].type.name.toString()),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 15,
     ),
  ),
```